# Service variables reset when calling activity closed in android

Tags: c#, android, service, xamarin, bind

I am having this issue for a couple of days now, i did a lot of searching in the Internet, but did not find something that works in my case.

I have a service :

```
namespace Demo_Service_Name
{
    public static class MyGlobals
    {
        ...
        public static int DurSelection;
    }

    class Service_Connection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
    {...}

    public class Demo_Service : Service
    {
        public void Setup_Service(int DSel)
        {
            MyGlobals.DurSelection = DSel;
        }

        public int Get_Duration_Selection()
        {
            return MyGlobals.DurSelection;
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

and my `Activity` goes like this:

```
using Demo_Service_Name
namespace Demo_Activity
{
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            ....
            ThisService = new Intent(this, typeof(Demo_Service));
            if (isMyServiceRunning())
            {
                demoServiceConnection = new Neural_Service_Connection(this);
                isBound = BindService(ThisService, demoServiceConnection, Bind.none);
                int servVar = binder.GetDemoService().Get_Duration_Selection();
            }
        }

        protected void OnStartMyService()
        {
            ....
            StartService(ThisService);
            isBound = BindService(ThisService, demoServiceConnection, Bind.none);
            binder.GetDemoService().Setup_Service(A_Certain_Number);
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is to start the service from the activity, bind to it, pass a value, close the activity, reopen the activity and read the variable back into the activity if the service is running.

All works like it should, except that when i close the activity, the value in the service variable is reset.

What do you think am I missing?

PS. I am sure the `Service.OnDestroy` has not been called